# ! LaTeX Error: File `path.sty' not found

Tags: errors, packages

This is a new install of Latex on RedHat7 but when I run check_latex there are missing items.

```
[root@devrhel7 ~]# pdflatex /opt/webwork/webwork2/bin/check_latex.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/opt/webwork/webwork2/bin/check_latex.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))

! LaTeX Error: File `path.sty' not found.
```

Comment: This may be a new install, but you have installed an old version of the TeX distribution. The second line says `TeX Live 2013`, the current version is `TeX Live 2019`. Maybe `path.sty` was not part of the distribution then.

Comment: Quote from http://webwork.maa.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Hardcopy: "For CentOS (and some other Linux distributions), the default install of texlive is somewhat poor, and it is recommended that you manually install the full TUG package set (see CentOS forums for more details). The header files for WeBWorK require the path package from texlive, which doesn't install nicely via yum or dnf on CentOS, hence the necessary manual install."

Comment: Off-topic: Never run `pdflatex` with `root` privileges.